# Moqui / PopCommerce: country-specific postal address format profiles?

Tags: moqui, hivemind

I'm totally new to Moqui/PopCommerce and my first impressions of it are great.

One thing that I didn't find how to do was country-specific postal address formatting: unfortunately, every country has a different address format, with  different fields, ordering and arrangement of the fields. 
For example, in most of Europe, the Zip code is expected left of the city name and there is no '#' sign in front of the house number. In France, the house number is left of the street and followed by a comma.
Some countries e.g. in Asia even have multiple address formats depending on other factors (e.g. rural vs city)

You can see explanations and examples here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_(geography)#Format_by_country
http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/postal/

So for any software that handles postal addresses, there are at least two situations where that country-specific address formatting is relevant:
1. in any output of a postal address (e.g. display, printout, mail, pdf, etc.)
2. in input of a postal address (e.g. address input form)

While an input form that doesn't adapt to the country-specific format is only a secondary problem (at least as long as it is only used by internal users and not external customers), any address output (especially one that is seen by any external customers) really HAS to conform to the country-specific address format and order, which means that there should be some way in the input form to choose an address format profile (e.g. by adapting to the chosen country).

I didn't see how to do that easily. I did find a PostalAddressSimpleTemplate variable in /vapps/system/Localization , but as I understand it, adding translations there would make the output dependent on the locale chosen by the user and not on the country of the address.

So my questions are:
* Is there any easy way to do this? (maybe I just didn't find it?)
* If not, is this something that would likely be added in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

To date the functionality in SimpleScreens (which is where the postal address entry forms and display templates are located) is more USA oriented because all of the sponsorship for it has been by companies in the USA. There have been a few contributions that are localization related, and a few localization components that others have built (see the Add Ons page on moqui.org), but these particular forms seem to be customized rather than made more dynamic to work better across a wider variety of locales.

If you are targeting a specific locale the best thing to do is plugin your own address entry form and display template, and if you are building a public facing web site you probably shouldn't use the forms or templates from SimpleScreens anyway (all are meant for internal applications, or portal sorts of sites for external users with a limited scope, but really not for ecommerce and other sorts of sites where they are publicly available and users won't use them enough to be able to use them with no training or documentation, or from another point of view benefit from the standard UI patterns).

The OOTB input form has started to move in a more country-generic direction with the country drop-down being to the left of the state/province drop-down (for whatever sub-country region is used in the country) and the state/province drop-down reloads from the server when the country is changed.

The output structure (in the address .gstring file, for HTML output) doesn't currently do anything different based on the country.

These will both change over time, but right now basically to handle country-specific input forms or output templates customization is required.